# Regex Initialization problems

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

I'm working with a bit of legacy code, and I'm trying to add a new regex to a validator's enumerator, for our purposes labeled as "URL". As I understand it, each part of the enumerator can be called into a separate regex. At any rate, here's what I've got (and others follow, hence the trailing comma):

```
URL("[a-zA-Z0-9\r#;?-\'.:,!/\\s]{1,250}", "Up to 250 letters (upper and lower case), numbers, #, ;, ?, -, ', ., :, comma, !, /, blankspace and carriage return"),
```

I made a simple JUnit test to see if it was working correctly. It is not.

```
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal character range near index 15
[a-zA-Z0-9
#;?-'.:,!/\s]{1,250}
               ^
```

I'm trying to restrict input of type URL to be between 1 and 250 characters, which is what I thought I was doing, but Eclipse seems to take offense to this comma (I assume the comma is index 15). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
?-'
```

This is being interpreted as a range from the character `?` to the character `'`, which is invalid because `?` has code point 63, while `'` has code point 39. Ranges should go from low to high. But you probably didn't intend to have a range here. I imagine you intended a literal hyphen.

To fix the error, try escaping the hyphen:

```
?\\-'
```

The reason why the error message indicator in the wrong place is because of the `\r` in the regular expression. If you replace the newline with another character the indicator lines up with the incorrect range:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_#;?-'.:,!/\s]{1,250}
               ^
```

You could also use `\\r` instead of `\r` so that the error message is printed correctly.

Comment: re: Your edit -- I had intended for the regex to allow the newline character, but your answer seems to indicate that instead of having the regex allow the carriage return character, I made a carriage return within the regex itself. Is this true, or will the regex find carriage returns properly?

Comment: When you create a regex in the form of a Java string literal, you can go either way.  `\r` in the source code becomes a carriage return in the compiled class, and the regex compiler treats it like any other literal character.  On the other hand, `\\r` becomes `\r`, the *regex* for a carriage return.  In other words, the `\r` doesn't cause a problem  in the regex, just in the error message.

Comment: By the way, the character-class shorthand `\s` is equivalent to `[\x20\t\r\n\f\v]`, so the `\r` in your regex is redundant anyway.